# "Advanced Options" Fails to return "Command Prompt"

Tags: mbr, gpt

Pursuant to converting Windows 10 from BIOS to UEFI.  The [procedure](https://www.maketecheasier.com/convert-legacy-bios-uefi-windows10/#How-to-Convert-Legacy-BIOS-to-UEFI) calls for invoking the Command Prompt under "Advanced options", so as to invoke from the command line" `mbr2gpt /validate`

1. Access Command Prompt from Windows’s advanced startup by pressing Win + X.
2. Go to “Shut down or sign out” and click on the “Restart” button while holding the Shift key.
3. The above action will reboot your system to the Advanced Startup screen.
4. Go to “Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options” and select the option “Command Prompt.”

**The instructions indicate that I should see:**

[image]

I did not see these options when I performed Step 4: it returned only one item: "Startup Setup", which I do not seek to modify.

Why does Advanced options not return 6 menu items shown in the image?  What needs to be done to return the options in the image?

## UPDATE

Per Ramhound's request, the command  `Reagentc /info` (run from Administrator Terminal) returns:

Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) and system reset configuration
Information:

```
Windows RE status:         Disabled
Windows RE location:
Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 5eef9b95-2fe8-11ec-9fcd-8e4a3539d6f1
Recovery image location:
Recovery image index:      0
Custom image location:
Custom image index:        0
```

## UPDATE: USB Stick

I burned a Windows PE USB stick per the [Microsoft Procedure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive?view=windows-11) to overcome  the Command prompt obstacle.   Mission successful

Comment: You run MBR2GPT from within Windows NOT WinRE. In other words those instructions are absolutely incorrect.  As for the differences between the options. Are you sure the option is “Startup Setup”, that’s not even an option, from your screenshot.  I suspect due to NOT having a WinRE partition. You will want to confirm your device has UEFI not BIOS before attempting to run [MBR2GPT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt)

Comment: General FYI: [WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference) is [WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive) _(Windows Install USB)_ with specific [Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference#winpe-optional-components) required to make it a WinRE image, so you can also do the same by booting an Install USB → Open a terminal via `Shift`+`F10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Advanced options not return 6 menu items shown in the image? What needs to be done to return the options in the image?

The WinRE environment is disabled on your system.  You need to enable it by running the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
Reagentc /Enable
```

Once you have enabled the WinRE you can boot into Advanced Startup and your system will look like the screenshot you provided.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command is:

```
reagentc /enable
```

You must use lowercase characters.

Comment: Why have you copied the previous answer?

Comment: Cause it was written with a wrong syntax.

Comment: "The Windows RE image was not found."